# How to wait for all inner HTTP calls to complete?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an HTTP call that returns a list of items. For some of these items I need to make an additional HTTP call to get more data. How do I know when all the second tier calls are completed. I cannot use forkJoin because I need to do stuff with the data that is returned from each call.

```
  private getData = () =>
  {
    this.backendService.getWorkflows().subscribe(
      (response: IWorkflowMetadata[]) =>
      {
        let workflows: IWorkflowMetadata[] = response;
        let publishedWorkflows = workflows.filter(workflow => workflow.PublishedTime !== null);

        publishedWorkflows.forEach(publishedWorkflow =>
        {
          this.backendService.getWorkflow(publishedWorkflow.ID).subscribe(
            (response: string) =>
            {
              console.log(`${this.getMethodInfo('onCreateSchedule_createPayload')} getWorkflow: response: `, response);

              // do stuff with this data
            },
            (err) => { console.error(`Error during HTTP request: getWorkflow: `, err); },
            // () => { }
          );
        });
      },
      (err) => { console.error(`Error during HTTP request: getWorkflows: `, err); },
      // () => { }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at `concatMap`. This link explains the difference with `mergeMap` and shows you some examples: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Observable.forkJoin as below

```
private getData = () =>
  {
    this.backendService.getWorkflows().subscribe(
      (response: IWorkflowMetadata[]) =>
      {
        let workflows: IWorkflowMetadata[] = response;
        let publishedWorkflows = workflows.filter(workflow => workflow.PublishedTime !== null);
        const calls = [];
        publishedWorkflows.forEach(publishedWorkflow =>
        {

          calls.push(this.backendService.getWorkflow(publishedWorkflow.ID);
          Observable.forkJoin(calls).subscribe(
            (response: string) =>
            {
              console.log(`${this.getMethodInfo('onCreateSchedule_createPayload')} getWorkflow: response: `, response);

              // do stuff with this data
            },
            (err) => { console.error(`Error during HTTP request: getWorkflow: `, err); },
            // () => { }
          );
        });
         },
      (err) => { console.error(`Error during HTTP request: getWorkflows: `, err); },
      // () => { }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of subscribing use a switchMap to a combineLatest to avoid nested subscriptions.

```
this.backendService.getWorkflows().pipe(switchMap(
    response: IWorkflowMetadata[] => {
      let publishedWorkflows = response.filter(workflow => workflow.PublishedTime !== null);
      return combineLatest(
        publishedWorkflows.map(
          publishedWorkflow => this.backendService.getWorkflow(publishedWorkflow.ID)
        )
      );
    }
)).subscribe(responses: string[] => {
  // responses is an array of the responses from the combineLatest
});
```